# Webpack module not found error using import

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I have the following error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/app/entries/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './containers/App'
```

But it looks fine in my directory:

[image]

Comment: Import like this ->`import App from '../containers/App';`  `./` means file inside  the same directory.

Comment: BTW, shouldn't it be `import App from '../containers/App/index';` ?

Comment: Fixed grammar and removed react tag